# How to disable asset pipelining with rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I must be missing something, as I can't find a solution to disable the assets pipeline with Rails 6.0.2.2 and most of the solutions I could find refer to older version of rails (before webpacker).

I'm not sure I understand how this works exactly, but here is what I did:

I installed several packages, either with gems, or with yarn, and I added the necessary 'require' in the `app/javascript/packs/application.js` which now look like this:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("src/cocoon")
require("fullcalendar")
require("moment")
require("materialize")

import "controllers";
```

Now, for debugging purposes, I would like to prevent rails from pipelining these assets, therefore in my `/config/application.rb` I set 
`config.assets.enabled = false` but this has no effect.

I tried to add this in development mode (even though I read that in development mode rails is not supposed to pipeline assets) and this has no effect.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, and your help will be much appreciated.

P.S: If someone could also explain what is the difference between these two files, this would help a lot too:
`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` (which seems to have a different syntax for the 'require'
and
`app/javascript/packs/application.js`

Many thanks.

Comment: Both `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and `app/javascript/packs/application.js` have the same purpose. They are used as [manifest files](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives). The difference is that the former is the manifest file for the asset pipeline (Sprockets), while the latter is the manifest file for Webpacker.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I would like to prevent rails from pipelining these assets"* ? What is the behaviour you're trying to prevent? Do you want to serve Webpacker assets separate instead of them being bundled together in the manifest file?

Comment: Thank you @3limin4t0r , yes, instead of a single large js file, I would prefer to see each js file as a single script tag. I now understand there is sprocket and and webpacker, but it seems to me as they have the same purpose.In my case I included some js in both manifest, and I still have a single js file in the output. Also, on the paragraph below, the doc mention that in development (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development) the assets should be output in separate script tags...what is happening?

Comment: The documentation to which you are referring is about the asset pipeline (Sprockets). Both Sprockets and Webpacker have their own settings. So Sprockets might indeed be serving assets separate like described in the guide, while Webpacker still compiles the assets. There isn't an official Rails guide about Webpacker yet (as far as I can find), but the readme offers a great deal of documentation. [Do you have `:compile` set to `false` for development?](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#custom-rails-environments)

Comment: Many thanks again. Now I set compile to false but it has no effect.
in app/javascript/packs/application.js I have the following:
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("jquery");
my output tag:
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
of course I restarted the server